# Time Varying System Matrices in Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter, time-varying-covariate

Kalman filter can accommodate time varying system matrices. Equations to run the filter are the same and it preserves its optimality under linear gaussian model.

My question is the following:

Can the evolution of time varying system matrices be stochastic? In some references I seem to read between the lines that they should evolve deterministically. Does it mean that the entire filter breaks or do we simply lose optimality by making them stochastic?

For reference, please peek at section 3.2 of the following paper:

http://www.ims.cuhk.edu.hk/~cis/2012.1/CIS%2012-1-05.pdf

A similar comment is in Harvey's book on Kalman Filter.

Comment: The link does not work, can you add a full reference to the paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dynamic system is 
$$ x_t = A_t x_{t-1} + \eta_t $$
$$ y_t = B_t x_t + \varepsilon_t $$
Then when people say system matrices $A_t, B_t$ should be deterministic, this means that Kalman Filter gives you an estimate of state $x_t$ *conditional* on past and current values of parameters $$\mathbf E\left(x_t|\,y_t,\dots,y_1, \,A_t,\dots,A_1, \,B_t, \dots, B_1\right).$$
So when you do a filtering step to estimate this conditional expectation of state, you consider those matrices to be already known (observed) rather than unknown and random. Of course they can be realizations of some external random process (which is often the case) or be deterministic functions of time - this doesn't matter much.

What seems authors in above paper describe in 3.2 is an extension of KF when they assume $A_t, B_t$ to be random but they don't what to condition on their values when filtering. So they don't assume matrices to be known at the moment of filtering, but rather assume that they come from a distribution with known mean/variance.

Comment: So basically they can be stochastic but if they are known (already observed) at the time of filtering step then it is still OK. Did I understand it correctly? This was indeed my intuition but I couldn't put my finger on it. In that case my only concern is how come this filter going to converge to anything useful. If matrices are evolving deterministically it could track the dynamic evolution (smooth derivatives). But when stochastic (no derivatives, zigzags) even if the values are known it should throw off the filter. No?

Comment: If the Matrices are observed, does it mean the filter is still an optimal filter?

Comment: Yes, when matrices are fixed at the moment of filtering, then standard KF produces the true value of above expectation of state conditional on all so far observed data (of course, if you specified the model correctly). And conditional expectation is a mean-squared optimal estimate of current state (which is a random value).

Comment: In both cases the "path" of system matrices is deterministic by the moment of filtering, just if it was a realization of some random process, then it will be non-smooth, if it's a deterministic function of time - it may be smooth (or not). What matters is that you know the whole path till $t$ when you filter at $t$.

Comment: Note, that filter _does not_ "track" the path of system matrices as you mention above, that path is already known. it tracks the unknown path of _states_. 

When you say "filter converges" what do you mean?

Comment: When I said converge I meant in the lines of variance of estimation error shrinking. With stochastic evolution of matrices, although their values are known in advance, such a convergence is hard to imagine. There must be some properties of the stochastic process of Matrices to achieve such a result.

Comment: Then if your system matrices changes abruptly, I guess it may increase conditional variance produced by filter. That's an interesting question how much this variance affected by parameters' changes. Anyway filter still will be optimal. But covariance may not diminish with time - that I can't say for sure :)

Comment: Note also, that you don't need to know future path of matrices to do filtering - just past path.

Comment: Yes. That's true unless you need a multistep forecast. Then you are doomed, I suppose. Anyhow, your answer is accepted together with the bounty (in 3 hours when system allow). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the evolution of time varying system matrices be stochastic?

Yes. If your model is
$$ x_t = A_t x_{t-1} + \eta_t $$
$$ y_t = B_t x_t + \varepsilon_t $$
and you assume further that $A_t$ and $B_t$ are themselves latent Markov processes, then you might have a model amenable to particle filtering, and in particular Rao-Blackwellized or marginal particle filters. Using these, it will be possible to obtain sampling-based approximations to distributions of the form
$$
p(x_{t} \mid y_{1:t}),
$$
which would be considered a marginal of the filtering distribution. You wouldn't have to condition on unknown quantities such as $B_t$ or $A_t$.

I have some [fast c++ code](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pf/blob/master/include/pf/rbpf.h) that will allow you to obtain the filtering distributions for models with pretty general dynamics on the "system matrices." Subclass `rbpf_kalman` with your own model, and all of the functionality is there ready to go.

Comment: github link is broken

Comment: @LudvigH fixed.